Multiple PROGRAM-ID's without matching END PROGRAM
I am trying to implement a simple calculator in COBOL and struggling with a particular issue.
My compiler, GNU Cobol 3.2.0 is always giving me this issue and I do not know how to fix ist.
The error is:
jdoodle.cobc:132: error: multiple PROGRAM-ID's without matching END PROGRAM
130 | exit program.
131 |
132 > 
My code:
identification division.
program-id. taschenrechner.
data division.
working-storage section.
01 zahl_1 pic 9(10).
01 zahl_2 pic 9(10).
01 ergebnis pic 9(10).
01 rechenoperator pic 9(10).
01 clear_screen_counter pic 9(10).
01 zahl_1_str pic z.
01 zahl_2_str pic z.
01 ergebnis_str pic z.


procedure division.

    *> Rechenoperation abfragen
    *> Rechenoperationen in vier verschiedenen Methoden implementieren
    *> Ergebnis returnen
    
    display 'Taschenrechner in COBOL.'.
    display ' '.
    display 'Bitte wählen Sie einer der folgenden Optionen aus:'.
    display ' '.
    display 'Tippen Sie 1 für Addition'.
    display 'Tippen Sie 2 für Subtraktion'.
    display 'Tippen Sie 3 für Multiplikation'.
    display 'Tippen Sie 4 für Division'.
    display ' '.
    
    move 1 to rechenoperator.
    
    display 'Geben Sie die erste Zahl ein:'.
    move 1 to zahl_1.
    
    display 'Geben Sie die zweite Zahl ein:'.
    move 1 to zahl_2.
    

        
        
        
identification division.
program-id. addition.
data division.
    linkage section.
    01 zahl_1 pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_2 pic 9(10).
    01 ergebnis pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_1_str pic z.
    01 zahl_2_str pic z.
    01 ergebnis_str pic z.
procedure division.
    
    add zahl_1 to zahl_2 giving ergebnis.
    
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    display 'Das Ergebnis der Addition zwischen ' zahl_1_str ' und ' zahl_2_str ' lautet: ' ergebnis_str.
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
exit program.
  
  
  
    
identification division.
program-id. subtraktion.
data division.
    linkage section.
    01 zahl_1 pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_2 pic 9(10).
    01 ergebnis pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_1_str pic z.
    01 zahl_2_str pic z.
    01 ergebnis_str pic z.
procedure division.
    
    subtract zahl_1 from zahl_2 giving ergebnis.
    
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    display 'Das Ergebnis der Subtraktion zwischen ' zahl_1_str ' und ' zahl_2_str ' lautet: ' ergebnis_str.
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
exit program.
    
    
    
    
identification division.
program-id. multiplikation.
data division.
    linkage section.
    01 zahl_1 pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_2 pic 9(10).
    01 ergebnis pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_1_str pic z.
    01 zahl_2_str pic z.
    01 ergebnis_str pic z.
procedure division.
    
    multiply zahl_1 by zahl_2 giving ergebnis.
    
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    display 'Das Ergebnis der Multiplikation zwischen ' zahl_1_str ' und ' zahl_2_str ' lautet: ' ergebnis_str.
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
exit program.
    
    
    
    
identification division.
program-id. division.
data division.
    linkage section.
    01 zahl_1 pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_2 pic 9(10).
    01 ergebnis pic 9(10).
    01 zahl_1_str pic z.
    01 zahl_2_str pic z.
    01 ergebnis_str pic z.
procedure division.
    
    divide zahl_1 by zahl_2 giving ergebnis.
    
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    display 'Das Ergebnis der Division zwischen ' zahl_1_str ' und ' zahl_2_str ' lautet: ' ergebnis_str.
    display '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
exit program.
    


I would be very thankful if someone could help me out.
I googled and tried to implement fixes that unfortunately did not work.

It looks like the compiler cannot guess where one set of statements ends, and the next one starts.  Trsay adding an END PROGRAM statement at the end of each source block.

I get this error now:
jdoodle.cobc:40: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFICATION
38 |     stop run
39 |
40 > identification division.
41 | program-id. addition.
42 | data division.
jdoodle.cobc:58: error: syntax error, unexpected END PROGRAM
56 |     display '------------------------------------------------------------..
57 |
58 >     end program.
59 |
60 | identification division.

I don't have this compiler so am unable to test it myself. I got the information from the GNU Cobol website.

exit program.

Does not end the scope of the nested program. Replace each occurrence of exit program. with end program followed by the program-name. At the end of the source add the end program for the main program.
identification division.
program-id. taschenrechner.
...

identification division.
program-id. addition.
...
end program addition.

identification division.
program-id. subtraktion.
...
end program subtraktion.

identification division.
program-id. multiplikation.
...
end program multiplikation.

identification division.
program-id. division.
...
end program division.

end program taschenrechner.


It worked, but I was missing some "." dots, thank you!
